# Developing Sudoku program in web application

Tags: java, web, sudoku

I am working on a case study to develop a sudoku program in java web application.I am confused with the approach to follow for it.Can any body help to clear questions.

1. How i can filled some valid cells with numbers in sections so user can get a flow to fill sudoku. Is there any inbuild API available?
2. Once display sudoku game in web application which approach is good to go for allow user to fill it?

Appreciating you comments...

Comment: I wanted to do it in java

Comment: Web is overflowing with Java Sudoku samples.  Have you even tried to search?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by ensuring that every row, column, and square of nine contains the following:

A) Only one digit numbers

B) No 0s

C) No duplicates

You can use some 'if' statements to check this.

You could also use a statement to ensure that each row, column, and square of nine totals 45, just to have a 'double check' in place (9 + 8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 45). Doing this alone would not be efficient, because someone could easily use doubles to add up to 45 (Ex: 9 + 9 + 9 + 5 + 4 + 4 + 3 + 1 + 1 = 45).

I would also determine a total number of squares that you would like to fill (out of 81), and I would implement a variable that tracks each square as it is filled. A 'for' loop would work for this.

I am not going to write all of the code out, because that's not what this site is for. But, I thought I would at least explain a few concepts that might help you out. I hope I have helped.

Comment: Thanks Ryan..
These validation will be helpful for me while user playing sudoku to make sure a valid sudoko...